# Proxy nexus instance unable to download the artifacts from remote

Tags: maven, build, nexus

I configured a proxy instance of a remote "Snapshots" repository using the nexus UI. I can browse the remote repository in the UI and take a look at the artifacts. I tried querying the remote nexus instance and it serves the artifacts without any issue. But when i try to hit a similar query on the proxy instance it gives me a resource "Not Found" error. I tried to use the "?describe" directive at the end of the URL to see exactly how the request was getting processed. But that did not give much info.

The proxy instance is empty even though the remote instance does have artifacts and i explicitly queried the proxy instance for artifacts present in remote so technically it should have fetched those artifacts and served but it did not work according to the plan. I also tried doing "Expire Cache" and change the setting "Not found cache TTL" to 0 but failed to make it work.

On my proxy i created a new "Snapshots-proxy" repo that proxies remote "Snapshots" repo.
Excerpts from nexus.xml:

```
<repository>
  <id>snapshots-proxy</id>
  <name>Snapshots-proxy</name>
  <providerRole>org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.Repository</providerRole>
  <providerHint>maven2</providerHint>
  <localStatus>IN_SERVICE</localStatus>
  <notFoundCacheActive>true</notFoundCacheActive>
  <userManaged>true</userManaged>
  <exposed>true</exposed>
  <browseable>true</browseable>
  <writePolicy>READ_ONLY</writePolicy>
  <indexable>true</indexable>
  <searchable>true</searchable>
  <localStorage>
    <provider>file</provider>
  </localStorage>
  <remoteStorage>
    <provider>apacheHttpClient3x</provider>
    <url>http://xxx.pod.dev.net:nnnn/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
        <id>http://xxx.pod.dev.net:nnnn/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</id>
        <url>http://xxx.pod.dev.net:nnnn/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>
  </remoteStorage>
  <externalConfiguration>
    <repositoryPolicy>RELEASE</repositoryPolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>WARN</checksumPolicy>
    <fileTypeValidation>false</fileTypeValidation>
    <downloadRemoteIndex>true</downloadRemoteIndex>
    <artifactMaxAge>-1</artifactMaxAge>
    <metadataMaxAge>1440</metadataMaxAge>
    <autoBlockActive>true</autoBlockActive>
  </externalConfiguration>
</repository>
```

I will greatly appreciate if someone can guide me where to look.

Answer (score 0):

A member of the sonatype community helped me figure out the problem. The error was in line:

```
    <repositoryPolicy>RELEASE</repositoryPolicy>
```

I changed it to SNAPSHOT and now it works!